# Error debugging the IOS Extensions in Visual Studios Xamarin

Tags: ios, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The issue I am having is that I can't debug the share extension. I've tried setting break points in the share extension and they are never hit.  If I attempt to debug the main app, all works as expected.

This is what I've done. Any help is appreciated!

I tried setting the share extension project as the startup project and I've tried setting multiple projects as startup and then when I run I get the following error:

In the IDE..."Launching Share Extension" and then after a few minutes the error "App has terminated"

Has anyone been successful at debugging an IOS extension using visual studios Xamarin?

Comment: Make sure you are using `XVS 4.3.0.550 (RC)` and a matching macOS Xamarin installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by SushiHangover, debugging iOS extensions in Visual Studio is available in 4.3.0.550 (RC) and introduced in [4.3.0.405](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.3/#4.3.0.405).

As of this writing, 4.3.0.550 is available through the [beta channel](https://releases.xamarin.com/beta-release-cycle-9-rc-builds/).

As a note, make sure that your Mac Build Agent is running on the same version.

Comment: You are ref'ing an old forum thread. **`XVS 4.3.0.405`** added debug support for extensions and thus **`XVS 4.3.0.550 (RC)`** does has debug extension support in Visual Studio

Comment: @SushiHangover Are you certain? I looked up the release notes of 4.3.0.550 as well and didn't see debug extension support for iOS mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Look at the release notes of when the initial support was added: `XVS 4.3.0.405` You can also follow the PRs of the Xamarin.iOS repo to look at the inclusion of support. I tend to use XS/VS4M 90% of the time, but I have clients actively debugging .appex in XVS.

Comment: @SushiHangover I absolutely overlooked that one bullet point in 405. Good catch!

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Just a personal note, `.appex` debugging can be a little rough around the edges (in the .405 RC it is fairly stable) so I still tend to use a number of `Writeline`s in async/thread areas. I also tend to avoid packages and instead import 3rd-party C# source and merge them into the same namespace of extension-based project to aid the Xamarin linker (but I would not recommend going down this path until you have to due to size rejections)

Comment: Thank you both!  I've updated and now it attempts to debug the extension.  Unfortunately, it's failing for some reason. Going to do some research but you've solved the mystery lol @SushiHangover

Comment: Don't hesitate to post more questions if you are in need of more answers :) We'll be waiting here for you.